# can't retrieve data from post in controller in ASP.Net Mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two forms on my ASP.Net View,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("saveData", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "validate" }))
{
<div class="formular-container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ccBesucherFirma)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ccBesucherFirma, new { @class = "form-control firma" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ccBesucherFirma)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ccBesucherName)
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ccBesucherName, new { @class = "form-control name" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ccBesucherName)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ccBesucherDatum)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ccBesucherDatum, new { @class = "form-control datum", ID = "datepicker", placeholder = "" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ccBesucherDatum)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ccAnsprechpartnerTurck)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ccAnsprechpartnerTurck, new { @class = "form-control contact" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ccAnsprechpartnerTurck)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-default" id="entry" type="submit">Eintragen</button>
            </div>
        }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("editData", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "validate" }))
    {
        <div id="overlay">
            <div id="overlay-container">
                <table class="overlay-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ccBesucherFirma)</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ccBesucherFirma, new { @class = "form-control overlay-input firma", disabled = "" })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ccBesucherName)</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ccBesucherName, new { @class = "form-control overlay-input name", disabled = "" })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ccBesucherDatum)</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ccBesucherDatum, new { @class = "form-control overlay-input datum", id = "datepicker", disabled = "" })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ccAnsprechpartnerTurck)</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ccAnsprechpartnerTurck, new { @class = "form-control overlay-input contact", disabled = "" })</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div id="EditResult"></div>

                <button class="btn btn-default overlay-button" type="button" id="print">Ausweis Drucken</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default overlay-button" type="button" id="edit">Bearbeiten</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default close-overlay overlay-button" type="reset" value="xModel">Schließen</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

One to save the data to the database and the other to edit mistakes in the data. I read that it would possible to use two forms, without a problem so I just put another form in my view and hoped for the best.
Now my problem is, that the second form won't post any data to my controller.
For this I tried alot of ways but none succeeded.
Here are my tries:

First I tried to use a form like you see above in my View. I need to mention something with the form, I'm editing the edit button with jquery so that it gets the attribute `type="submit"`because I don't want to delete and create the button.

In Javascript/Jquery with ajax:

```
        var firma = $(".firma").val();
        var name = $(".name").val();
        var datum = $(".datum").val();
        var contact = $(".contact").val();
        var formData = [firma,name,datum,contact];

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/editData",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            success: function(myData) {
                $("#EditResult").html(myData);
            }
        });
```

And at last my Controller, where the data should end up:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult editData(BesucherausweisModel xFormData)
{

    var a = xFormData;

    return View("Index");
}
```

EDIT:
Here's the class:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Firma")]
public string ccBesucherFirma { get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Name")]
public string ccBesucherName { get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Datum")]
public string ccBesucherDatum { get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Ansprechpartner")]
public string ccAnsprechpartnerTurck { get; set; }
```

Can anybody tell what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: Ok, my Instructor told me to not work on this project anymore, I still thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the point of the 2 forms - they both contain controls for the same properties - what is the difference between your `saveData()` and `editDate()` methods? And you have invalid html because both `<form>` tags have the same `id` attribute and every control has a duppicate `id` attribute. The script will only ever ever get the values of the controls in the first form

Comment: And then `var formData = [firma,name,datum,contact];` generates and array which will not bind to parameter `BesucherausweisModel xFormData`

Comment: I didn't notice the same Id, but I tested it with different IDs and changed the parameter to a `string[]`but I stil do not get any Data

Comment: Of course not, but what are you actually trying to do with this. What is the point of the 2 forms for exactly the same data. And what does your `editData()` method actually do (that cant be the real code because it does absolutely nothing)

Comment: The first form saves the data to the database without editing it and the second form is to edit said data if mistakes were made in this data. I want to split up my functions to keep a clear view over my code and know excactly where errors appear.

Comment: And the function does appear useless but I'm testing if the data I need is actually posted to my controller.

Comment: Sorry, but this is nonsense. You have one form (this first one). If the model is not valid when you submit, then you return the view (with error messages displayed) so 'mistakes' can be corrected. Only when the model is valid do you save and redirect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80640/discussion-between-flowx-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you serialization misses properties names. Add unique ids to your forms and try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Home/editData",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $('#some-unique-id').serialize(),
        success: function(myData) {
            $("#EditResult").html(myData);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Note that there are two form elements with the same `id`, so your `#validate` selector will only ever get the elements from the first form.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are in right direction, only need some correction in ajax call.
Find below code:

step 1) Confirm your BesucherausweisModel having public properties for below attributes:

```
class BesucherausweisModel
{
    public string Firma {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Datum {get; set;}
    public string Ansprechpartner {get; set;}
}
```

step 2) pass data by ajax call like below way:

```
var xFormData = {};
xFormData.Firma = $(".firma").val();
xFormData.Name = $(".name").val();
xFormData.Datum = $(".datum").val();
xFormData.Ansprechpartner = $(".contact").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/editData",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(xFormData),
    success: function(myData) {
        $("#EditResult").html(myData);
    }
});
```

Please let me know, is this works for you?

Comment: So, I tried but it still returns `null` my Controller

Comment: Please post your BesucherausweisModel class code here

Comment: Try this. I have updated answer, as per your updated question.

Comment: Still returns null :/

Comment: add alert(xFormData); before ajax call, and please let me know xFormData having data or not ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80644/discussion-between-rohit-sonaje-and-flowx).